# Можно ли получить сегменты маршрута с control.RoutePanel?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Можно ли получить сегменты маршрута с control.RoutePanel? И можно ли добавить кнопку редактирования маршрута?

Comment: Зачем нужна кнопка редактирования маршрута? Если панель позволяет редактировать маршрут построенный через неё.

Comment: Кажется ровно ваша задача [описана в документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/router/routePanel-docpage/?from=SO#routePanel__get-route-info)

Comment: http://joxi.ru/gmvGDzuL8yn82a где эта кнопка редактирования на панели?

Comment: Если вы открыли панель, то вы можете удалить точки, отредактировать их и построить маршрут из двух точек. Вы хотите чего-то другого?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, редактировать маршрут значит добавить промежуточные точки и  изменить линию маршрута потянув за неё. Как это сделать при панели?

Comment: Спасибо Reni, получил сегменты. Подскажите как их вывести внизу http://joxi.ru/gmvGDzuL8yn82a под инпутами

Comment: "Насколько я понимаю, редактировать маршрут значит добавить промежуточные точки и изменить линию маршрута потянув за неё. Как это сделать при панели?" В панели этого сделать нельзя. Если вы хотите такую функциональность, то придется реализовать панель полностью самостоятельно. Вот тут пример, как добавить собственный контрол на карту: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_control

Comment: "Подскажите как их вывести внизу joxi.ru/gmvGDzuL8yn82a под инпутами" Для того чтобы это сделать тоже нужно реализовать панель полностью самостоятельно. Выше кинул пример.